# whenever i create a venv and then pip freeze still all the global packages are shown

Tags: python, django, python-3.7

I am new to Django and was following a tutorial where a venv was setup for the project directory but after doing pip freeze only pip was there but in my all the global packages are still shown.

Comment: You need to *activate* the virtual environment

Comment: Install virtual env wrapper package and type "workon virtualenv_name"

Answer (score 0):

Have you activated your virtualenv? If you named your virtualenv venv as you seem to imply, make sure you've run:

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

in the directory containing your virtualenv.

Comment: I am in windows so is the command source venv/Scripts/activate or ./Scripts/actiavte.bat ??

Comment: In windows it should be .\Scripts\activate